# Chrome extension to easily edit local storage

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a Chrome Extension that lets me **easily** edit local stoage values?

Specifically - if I have a nested JSON value in local storage Chrome Dev Tools gives me a single text box to edit it and it would be nice if there was a better interface that let me edit/delete keys without copy/pasting the text out of the text box and into an editor that formatted the JSON, editing it, and pasting the result back in.

Comment: Use [Storage Area Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb) or an analog.

Comment: that gives me a bigger textbox